# Call a class attribute which is a string type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my class implementation

```
class A:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.result = None
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.add()

    def add(self):
        self.result = self.a+self.b
        return
```

My class **A** has result as an **attribute**. I want to access the class attribute i.e; result by reading the result string from dictionary. Below is the implementation I tried.

```
x = 'result' # I will get from other source
obj = A(1,2)
obj.x # Here x = result and the result is the actual class attribute

Error:
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'x'
```

Could anyone tell me how to access the class attributes by converting the string to object?

Comment: you shoud not overwrite `str`; that is a built-in...

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically compose and access class attributes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286089/how-to-dynamically-compose-and-access-class-attributes-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)**

`getattr` will do exactly what you're asking.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.result = ''
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.add()

    def add(self):
        self.result = self.a+self.b
        return

x = 'result' # I will get from other source
obj = A(1,2)
obj.add() #this was missing before thus obj.result would've been 0
print getattr(obj, x) # Here x = result and the result is the actual class attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

As John mentions, `getattr` is probably what you are looking for.  As an alternative, every object has a `__dict__` variable containing key value pairs:

```
obj = A(1,2)
obj.add()
print(obj.__dict__.get('result'))
```

You are better off in the general case, however, using `getattr`

Comment: The selected answer to this question mentions why `getattr` is preferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084897/getattr-versus-dict-lookup-which-is-faster